# Codeigniter routes & .htaccess permanent remove

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am upgrading my system and built it in Codeigniter.

I now need to rewrite old website URL's to be redirected to the new system URL structure.

Old URL looks like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/top-category/two-subcategory/2-13-123453/title.html
```

The new URL will be something like:

```
http://www.domain.com/advertise/2-13-123453/title.html
```

I tried the following in my .htaccess file with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /advertise/$3/$4 [L,R=301]
```

I then unsuccessfully tried to see if I can fix it making use of the Ci routes file with:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "advertise/index/$3/$4";
```

Not sure what else I should try or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it working with the following just after RewriteBase /

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([0-9-]+)/(.*)$ /advertise/$5/$6 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([0-9-]+)$ /advertise/$5 [L,R=301]
```